# Add new SAS variable whilst retaining integrity constraints

Tags: sas

So I need to modify (with new column) an existing SAS table which has integrity constraints.  Of course I can proc sql; "describe" the table and rebuild the constraint, am just wondering if there is an alternative (batch) method which does not involve such a step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just `ALTER` the SAS dataset to add the new column, which will not affect any other defined attributes (like indexes or integrity constraints).  For example:

```
proc sql noprint;
    alter table MYLIB.SOME_DATASET
       add NEW_VARIABLE char(25) format=$25.;
quit;
```